# How to get result back to the parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having the below set of Activities :

Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3

I have launched Activity 2 from Activity 1 using startActivityForResult and after some work in Activity 2, I finished Activity 2 and started Activity 3 from Activity 2 using same startActivityForResult.

Now when I press back button on Activity 3, I want to handle the result in onActivityResult of Activity 1. The control is going in Activity 3 but the result code is coming as 0, so I have added setResult in Activity 3 on backPressed but it is still giving the result code as 0 in Activity 1.

How can I do this, please help me If anyone know about this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

Don't finish activity2 when going to activity 3. Instead of finish activity 2 when you came on onActivityResult of Activity2, and again sent result back to Activity 1

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish the activity2  when you launch the Activty3, so you can get the result in activity2's `onActivityResult` method, at that time you set again the same `setResult` method with the data you get from Activity3 and finish activity2 here, so now you get the result in Activity1.

your reverse flow like this:

Activity3 ->setResult ->finish activity3 -> onAcitvityResult in Activity2 -> get the data and setResult -> finisht acitvity2 -> onAvtivityResult in Activity1